# XSLT processing on IE11?

Tags: xslt, internet-explorer-11

What has happened to the XSLT processing in IE11?

On IE8/9/10, you can use:

```
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate");
    ....
}
```

On Chrome/Firefox/Safari, you can use:

```
else { 
    var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
}
```

But on IE11, neither of these are supported. Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a version number? `var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate.6.0");`.

Comment: Ah sorry, just amended question -- turns out it was the "window.ActiveXObject" check that fails on IE11 (but if you attempt to create it anyway, it works)

Comment: its worth noting that the Chrome devs recently proposed removing their built-in xslt processor on the grounds that no-one uses it. See https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/zIg2KC7PyH0. In light of this, you might want to re-think relying on it being built into the browser.

Comment: On my IE11 I get undefined on `var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate.6.0"); console.log(xslt)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
if (window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject" in window)
```

This worked for me working with IE11 and allowed me to instantiate ActiveX objects since the standard old check was being bypassed.

Comment: This will detect all IE versions 5-11.  If you want just IE 11 specifically, try this: `!(window.ActiveXObject) && "ActiveXObject" in window`

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on Chrome/Edge/Firefox/IE11

```
 function loadXMLDoc(filename) {
     if (window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject" in window) {
         xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
     } else {
         xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
     xhttp.send("");
     return xhttp.responseXML;
 }


 if (window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject" in window) {
     ie();
 } else {

     xml = loadXMLDoc("input.xml");
     xsl = loadXMLDoc("mmlctop2_0.xsl");

     if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
         xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
         xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
         resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xml, document);

         var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
         var transformed = serializer.serializeToString(resultDocument.documentElement);

         alert(transformed);
     }
 }

 // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753809(v=vs.85).aspx
 function ie() {

     var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate.3.0");
     var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.3.0");
     var xslProc;
     xslDoc.async = false;
     xslDoc.load("mmlctop2_0.xsl");
     if (xslDoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) {
         var myErr = xslDoc.parseError;
         alert("You have error " + myErr.reason);
     } else {
         xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc;
         var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0");
         xmlDoc.async = false;
         xmlDoc.load("input.xml");
         if (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) {
             var myErr = xmlDoc.parseError;
             alert("You have error " + myErr.reason);
         } else {
             xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
             xslProc.input = xmlDoc;
             xslProc.addParameter("param1", "Hello");
             xslProc.transform();
             alert(xslProc.output);
         }
     }


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider [Saxon CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml), an XSLT 2.0 processor implemented entirely in JavaScript.  This would give you a consistent API across all browsers and would allow you to code using the more powerful XSLT 2.0 language rather than 1.0.

Comment: Interesting idea, wonder how performant this is compared to the browser native implementations?

Comment: Is it open source?

Answer (score 1):

The reason `if(window.ActiveXObject)` fails in IE11 is because for some reason `window.ActiveXObject` has become [falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/), even though it is still a function. I've taken to being more explicit in my feature detection:

```
if(window.ActiveXObject !== undefined){
    ...
}
```

This approach also covers the case of checking for attributes that are present but not set to a truthy value:

```
if(document.createElement("span").draggable !== undefined){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me running site in a **compatibility mode** in IE - 11 solved the issue....

Note : This might not be a solution , but I was in a situation where one if my old site was using above mentioned code. But I'm not in a position to Re-code the site

Answer (score 0):

You Can use (**"ActiveXObject" in window**) which will allow all the IE browsers to come inside the if condition .
Exp :-

```
if ("ActiveXObject" in window) {
// Internet Explorer For all versions like IE8 , IE9 , IE10 or IE11 etc
}else{
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
        }
```