# Error : 'XSLTProcessor' is undefined ie11 (Only)

Tags: javascript, xslt, internet-explorer-11

I am getting an error "'XSLTProcessor' is undefined" only in IE 11.
I try to google it but didn't found anything useful.

Here is my code:

```
function attchmentList(p)
{
    var sender = new XMLHttpRequest();
    sender.open("GET","Attachments.aspx?id="+p, false); 
    sender.send(null);
    oDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(sender.responseText, "text/xml");

    var oItem = oDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
    document.getElementById("lblAttachments").innerHTML = oItem.length;


    oXSL = load("AttachmentList.xslt");

    var processor = new XSLTProcessor();
    processor.importStylesheet(oXSL);

    var o = processor.transformToDocument(oDoc);
    var CI_obj = document.getElementById("files_list");

    CI_obj.innerHTML = serialize(o);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You still need the `ActiveX` object in IE 11 - have a [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18891860/314291)